Changing color line based on slope with a categorical variable
I need the lines in this graph in two different colors depending on slope positive or negative:

This is my data in txt
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12V077r-LDycTI68t6wk_H4nfySvG0sNh/view?usp=drive_link
I have this code:
data<-read.table(choose.files(), sep = "\t", dec = ",", header = T)
attach(data)
str(data)
data$Plane.Moment <- factor(data$Plane.Moment, levels=c("AB", "AA", "PB", "PA"))
ggplot(data,aes(x = Plane.Moment, y = Indices, color = Plane.Moment)) +
geom_line(aes(group = Patient),linetype="dashed",lwd=0.8,color = "grey")+
geom_point(alpha=0.6, size=3)

And I wanted to use mutate calculating a slope as in  this post. But my X axis is a categorical variable not a number.

Welcome to SO, @Natali! In my experience you are far more likely to receive help if you follow the guidance available here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In particular, don't force potential helpers chase down links to access your data.

One approach is to add a trend indicator at the data stage.

generating sample data for you:


    data <- data.frame(Plane.Moment = factor(rep(c('AB', 'AA'), 2), levels = c('AB', 'AA')),
                       Indices = c(1, .8, 1, 1.2),
                       Patient = gl(2, 2, labels = paste('Patient', c('X', 'Y')))
    )
    
    ## > data
    ##   Plane.Moment Indices   Patient
    ## 1           AB     1.0 Patient X
    ## 2           AA     0.8 Patient X
    ## 3           AB     1.0 Patient Y
    ## 4           AA     1.2 Patient Y



make Plane.Moment a factor and specify levels to obtain the desired order (e. g., AA coming after AB)
compare the orders of Indices and Plane.Moment per patient. If they correspond, you have a stagnation or increase, if not, they develop in opposite directions (decrease):


    data <-   
      data |>
      mutate(trend = order(Indices) == order(Plane.Moment), .by = Patient)


use the trend to colour the lines:
data |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = Plane.Moment, y = Indices, group = Patient)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = trend))


Note:

there's no need to colour the points in your plot, because their association with a given Plane.Moment can immediately be inferred from their position along the y-axis (such redundant visual markers may falsely impress more dimensions than actually presented [here: Patient, Plane.Moment and Indices]). Similarly, colouring the lines by trend might help when there's really large numbers of overplotting lines but even in that case a boxplot might better tell the forest from the trees.

you can assign discrete numeric values to categorical values like so: c('Apple', 'Pear') |> factor() |> as.numeric()


